# Android: Best way to Display Images on a screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery, android-image

This could potentially be a duplicate but I after spending several hours reading about ImageView, ImageSwitcher, Gallery Views, Lazy Loads, and more I decided I should just ask.

I am working on an app and in one of the screens there may be an image or multiple images associate with what I am talking about.  The other data for this intent will be pulled from a local database.  In the database it will also have a list of URLs of images that are associate with each thing that I am discussing.  So I would like to know the best way to display a thumbnail of these pictures (if there are any) on the screen.  Then if these pictures are clicked on it can open up the bigger version of these pictures.  I don't necessarily want to download these pictures since I don't want to save them locally for the app.  Plus I don't want to make the page delay in loading while it waits to download the pictures.

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, since images aren't the main focus of my app, I decided to just embed a webview in my page and then display the image in some custom html ( I had a list of URLs to the images online).  I also calculate the width of the screen and then I adjust how wide the images are going to be in my html.

This was the easiest since the webview takes care of the "threaded" part and I don't have to worry about how to handle/save/and display the images.

It would have been helpful to see a best practices guide when it comes to android and handeling images.

Answer (score 0):

I have to caution you, that with newer versions of Android, applications can't make connections to the internet that build the UI directly on the UI thread. Instead, it must be accomplished in a background thread such as ASyncTask. So if you're going to go with making ImageViews without src in your XML, that's fine, but you can't just have the ImageViews go download their images via URL in the onCreate of your main activity any longer. It has to be done in the background, else you'll get an error.

It makes the process fairly more complex, to be honest, but it does improve application responsiveness.